# How to fade a background image while hover an element using css

Tags: css

I am using an element where a background image is applied. When I hover on this element the same background image should be faded a little. Can it possible without using second image.

Comment: Please try this while hover the element  - transition: background .5 ease;

Comment: @AntonySUTHAKARJ. It may be useful but I actually don't know the process to use this code. Can you please explain.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this so set a transparent layer over the element containing the image and fading this in and out. [See this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrbsveya/) for a working example.

CSS

```
.example {
height: 80px;
width: 200px;
background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/) 50% 50% no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

.example:after {
content: " ";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: red;
opacity: 0;
position: relative;
transition: .3s all;
}

.example:hover:after {
opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Please note that the transition needs prefixes to work in all browsers.

HTML

```
<div class="example"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/myhc5tfc/) :

```css
.image1{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-image: url("http://www.designsnext.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/nature-wallpapers-3.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   
}

.image1:hover{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-image:url("http://wallpapersshd.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/free-natural-wallpaper.jpg");
    background-size:100%;
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="image1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is fine and also useful. But can it possible to fade the same background image without using second image.